# how to send svg data to android application from website

Tags: svg, google-play, dynamic-data, android

what is the best way to read a dynamic data changed every minutes and send it to android application to refresh it's page.
supposing the android application is published on Google play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Google Cloud Messaging`:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

It allows you to send messages from your server to a registered device. Then in your application you just have to listen to GCM messages and refresh the page.

Comment: the server is an website or what?

Comment: I guessed the dynamic data you want to check is in your own server. Was I wrong?